# Easiest gui toolkit to learn and use for java

Tags: java, qt, user-interface, gtk, gnome

I want to learn GUI development for java. Can anyone recommend me some easy to learn and use GUI widget toolkits. I would also want to know a good GUI designer for the toolkit. The toolkit should integrate well with gtk and qt . Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Integrate well with GTK *and* QT" is pretty much a killer requirement. Apart from that I'd suggest Swing, simply because it comes with Java out-of-the-box. SWT might be relevant (I don't know if there's a Qt port, 'though).

Comment: "easiest", "good" are subjective. GTK it compiles to native, Java is for virtual machine.

Comment: Integrated in the sense, the interface looks like gnome or kde,whichever one it is being used on.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't really know why do you need an integration with gtk and qt.
Basically there are 4 main options when you're talking about gui for the desktop in java.

1. AWT - very outdated, don't use it unless you don't really need
2. SWT - much better, you'll get ui that looks like Eclipse (its written with SWT). A lot of people claim that its faster than Swing (see option 3)
3. Swing - a part of java standard libraries. Was developed as a replacment for AWT. Very solid (~12-13 years). Platform independent in implementation (your widgets look the same on all Operating systems). In modern java versions quite fast as well. Very flexible.
   I would recommend using Swing or SWT if you have to use java. I like Swing more but its solely my opinion. Drawbacks - 'as is' requires a lot of coding and you don't see how your page actually looks like (no mark up). Doesn't use any kind of scripting language.
   On top of Swing you can use stuff like Apache Pivot, but its entirely different story.
4. Java FX. Developed as a 'next generation ui' platform. requires java fx compiler (its not a java code but something that compiles into bytecode).
   Looks very nice, and a great platform by itself, it can be considered as a competitor for Flex and Silverlight. The main drawback is that its not that widespread because became avaiable too late after its competitors. As a result it has a relatively small community.

I don't know about integration with QT/GTK so I can't tell you much on it

Hope this helps

Comment: If I m not mistaken,isn't apache pivot and JavaFX for web apps? I Luke swt but I don't like eclipse. There does not seem to be any way to use swt without eclipse......

Comment: SWT is built by Eclipse but is perfectly suited for developing standalone GUI applications. In other words, you can use it *without* eclipse.